# Cant install Mesa/Vulkan drivers.. help!

Tags: release-hera

Has anyone had this issue trying to install lutris/graphics drivers on Elementory OS 5.1?

Im following [these](https://github.com/lutris/docs/blob/master/InstallingDrivers.md) instructions and i get the following error after running this command

sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 : Depends: libzstd1:i386 (>= 1.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have googled and cannot find any solution for this

Comment: Did you follow the "Ubuntu 18.04" section? elementary OS 5.1 is based on Ubuntu 18.04. The other instructions look like they're for newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi David yes i did follow the Ubuntu 18.04 section